# Boot option disappear when connecting two SSD drives

Tags: linux, windows, boot, bios, uefi

I have added a second SSD to my laptop replacing the DVD drive. On the first SSD Linux is installed and works fine. I have installed Windows 10 on my second SSD. Therefore I had to disconnect my first SSD in order to install Windows 10, otherwise you get an error code when selecting a disk during installation. 
When only the second SSD is connected, booting Windows 10 works fine. But when I connect both SSDs, the boot option for the second SSD disappears. 
Maybe it has something to do with BIOS/UEFI booting. Both SSDs are visible in the SATA configuration.

Extra information:

- First SSD: Samsung 830 with Linux Mint installed
- Second SSD: Samsung 750 EVO with Windows 10 installed

There is an option to add a boot option in the BIOS but I don´t know how it works.

Comment: Might be worth a try to see if there's an update for your BIOS

Comment: BIOS 202 (installed) is the latest version for the ASUS UX52VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I had to set the SATA controller to AHCI mode instead of IDE. And "Launch CSM" has to be enabled but "Launch PXE OpROM" disabled. 
Now the two SSDs are visible in the boot menu.